# Concat in update

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, concatenation

I have the following table

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3

1   A    B    NULL

2   A    B    NULL

3   A    B    NULL
```

I am trying to concat col1 and col2 in my third column.

I tried this :

```
update TABLE set Col3 = concat(col1, '', Col2);
```

But SQL Server told me that `concat` is unknown as an integrated function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the concatenation operator (the '+' sign) like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET Col3 = Col1 + Col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the + sign to concatenate. update TABLE set Col3 = col1 + ''+ Col2.
IF you are concatenating integers , convert them to varchar first.

```
UPDATE TABLE 
   SET [Col3] = CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),[col1]) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Col2])
```